# How can i save picture in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf

so i have a wpf app, there i have DrawingVisual object, let's call it "visual", also there is RenderTargetBitmap object, let's call it "target". I have some strings of code below.

```
DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
RenderTargetBitmap target = new RenderTargetBitmap(certBg.PixelWidth, certBg.PixelHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
target.Render(visual);
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = target;
```

How can i save that picture? I thought to use img.Save, but it doesn't work in WPF. I've tried to use BitmapEncoder but it was unsuccsessful. How shall i save on the disk that picture?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? The System.Drawing.Bitmap component in WPF has a Save functionality. Try using that instead of the Image control.

Comment: Eventually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161359/save-bitmapimage-to-file can help you.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471181/23074) help you?

Comment: @Lupu "System.Drawing.Bitmap component in WPF" doesn't make sense. System.Drawing.Bitmap is WinForms, not WPF. In WPF you would use a BitmapEncoder.